# Declaring static method in Singleton spring bean

Tags: java, spring, static, singleton, static-methods

We are running into memory leak issue and we suspect that below code could be reason, we have a static method in a singleton class and doubt that its causing memory leak while its being referenced directly.

```
// This class is wired in spring xml and loaded as spring bean
public class SpringSingletonRestClient{

// instance method to make a web-service call
public ServiceResponse getResponseFromARestService(String RequestParam){.....}

// public static helper bean mapping method, that is used outside this class 
// for converting the service response object to different object
public static DomainResponse convertServiceResponseToDomainResponse(ServiceResponse serviceResponse){ //conversion logic.... }
 }

}
```

**Usage**

```
Class MainClass {

//injected as spring bean
SpringSingletonRestClient client;

public void someMethod(){
ServiceResponse serviceResponse = client.getResponseFromARestService(...);
DomainResponse domainResponse =  SpringSingletonRestClient.convertServiceResponseToDomainResponse(serviceResponse);
// use domainResponse object
.......
.......
}

}
```

Please let me know if more clarification is required since I just added pseudo. 
We are running to high memory usage and we suspect that using the static method which is declared in a class that is initiated by the spring is not garbage collected correctly and there is memory leak happening because of it.

Question - Is it bad to have static methods in a Spring initiated singleton class even though that static method is used by direct reference and not used by its instance variable.

Comment: I don't see why using static method can cause a leak, but I should admit that when the class is a singleton it is assumed that it should never be collected (if you expect that)

Comment: Yes, I suspect that but not quite sure until I get to the root.

Answer (score 0):

The static method shouldn't cause a memory leak. It just means that the method doesn't use any class fields and can be invoked without a class instance. [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) explains this - check section Class methods

A memory leak typically happens because a "global" field holds on to a reference and never stops using it. This is may be a collection. You should something like JConsole to profile the memory usage and list the most used object. This should help you to narrow it down.

EDIT (more information):  You are calling a static method without initialising an object. i.e. there is not `new SpringSingletonRestClient()` anywhere.

```
DomainResponse domainResponse =  SpringSingletonRestClient.convertServiceResponseToDomainResponse(serviceResponse);
```

In the above line, spring is irrelevant. It is as if the method is a simple function within a procedural language. Therefore, this cannot cause a memory leak.

Comment: The problem occurs in long run, it doesn't increase the cpu usage right away but it takes a while. And we have new-relic profiling our production usage periodically in which we can see this methods is called several times concurrently and when GC is run the heap is cleared but the cpu memory usage keeps increasing and periodically crashes. Which shows that there is something leaking outside the heap.

Comment: I agree on the static method, but what I suspect is this static method is in the singleton class which is managed by spring. And if that is not being picked by GC. Still memory leaking is something that doesnt make any sense yet to me. I will run JConsole and see, thanks for the the suggestion.

Comment: are we talking about cpu usage or mem usage? As for mem usage, I have provided more info in the answer as to why the static method cannot be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense to me. Since we were not able to nail down the issue yet, we decided to move the static method outside this class to a helper class which is not initiated by spring. And then we would be running a load test simulating the same usage. Will update if we find any differences. But I agree on your response, thats where I was totally confused and was not sure.